# Django - how to permanently set I18N

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'd like to set permanently language for my site in a way that for example .de domain opens in Deutch language. I have one code for all markets but each has own translations.

In other words I'd like to avoid situation when someone has OS locale set on US and can see site in english despite the fact that he/she connects to .de domain.

Is there any way to enforce translation to specific language per installation?

Django 1.5

Thanks
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [LangByTldMIddleware](https://github.com/user2589/django-common-utils/blob/master/common_utils/middleware.py#L16) in my project, worked just fine.

UPD: I might have misunderstood the question. This middleware is useful if you serve several domains from the same filebase, and want to set default language basing on site TLD. If you handle only .de domain and want to force Deutch then just set LANGUAGES and LANGUAGE_CODE in settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', u'Deutsch'),
)
```